# How to set meta fields as optional while using pandas.io.json.json_normalize?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm running into fairly typical key error while using json_normalize.  I've already set errors="ignore".  Unfortunately that only applies to record values not meta values.  Has anyone found an effective way to make meta fields optional?  My goal is to query a json file with every possible field that client cares about and just return NaN for anything missing.

My example usage:

```
df = json_normalize(data, ['invoice-lines', 'account-allocations'], parent_fields , meta_prefix='invoice_', record_prefix='alloc_', errors='ignore')
```

My example error:

> KeyError: 'header-tax-rate'

My long list of "parent fields", meta fields:

```
parent_fields = [
"id",
"created-at",
"status",
"internal-note",
"invoice-date",
"invoice-number",
"line-level-taxation",
"supplier-note",
"header-tax-rate",
"header-tax-code",
"paid",
"payment-date",
"payment-notes",
"exported",
"account-type-id",
"account-type-name",
"payment-term",
"handling-amount",
"misc-amount",
"shipping-amount",
"total",
"currency",
"accounting-total-amount",
"accounting-total-currency",
"supplier-id",
"supplier-name",
"supplier-number",
"created-by-email",
"created-by-employee-number",
"created-by-login",
"updated-by-email",
"updated-by-employee-number",
"updated-by-login",
"attachment-texts",
"comments",
"remit-to-address.code",
"remit-to-address.attention",
"remit-to-address.street1",
"remit-to-address.street2",
"remit-to-address.city",
"remit-to-address.state",
"remit-to-address.postal-code",
"remit-to-address.country-code",
"remit-to-address.country-name",
"remit-to-address.name",
"remit-to-address.vat-number",
"remit-to-address.vat-country-code",
"remit-to-address.vat-country-name",
"supplier-vat-number",
"supplier-vat-country-code",
"document-type",
"original-invoice-number",
"original-invoice-date",
"bill-to-address.legal-entity-name",
"bill-to-address.attention",
"bill-to-address.street1",
"bill-to-address.street2",
"bill-to-address.city",
"bill-to-address.state",
"bill-to-address.postal-code",
"bill-to-address.country-code",
"bill-to-address.country-name",
"bill-to-address.name",
"ship-to-address.attention",
"ship-to-address.street1",
"ship-to-address.street2",
"ship-to-address.city",
"ship-to-address.state",
"ship-to-address.postal-code",
"ship-to-address.country-code",
"ship-to-address.country-name",
"ship-to-address.name",
"supplier-remit-to.code",
"supplier-remit-to.supplier-name",
"supplier-remit-to.street1",
"supplier-remit-to.street2",
"supplier-remit-to.city",
"supplier-remit-to.state",
"supplier-remit-to.postal-code",
"supplier-remit-to.country-code",
"supplier-remit-to.country-name",
"Fiscal Rep. Name",
"Fiscal Rep. VAT ID",
"Fiscal Rep. Address Code",
"Fiscal Rep. Address Street 1",
"Fiscal Rep. Address Street 2",
"Fiscal Rep. Address City",
"Fiscal Rep. Address State",
"Fiscal Rep. Address Postal Code",
"Fiscal Rep. Address Country Code",
"discount_due_date",
"net_due_date",
"discount_amount",
"late-payment-penalties",
"margin-scheme",
"cash-accounting-scheme-reference",
"exchange-rate",
"early-payment-provisions",
"pre-payment-date",
"reverse-charge-reference",
"discount-percent",
"credit-note-differences-with-original-invoice",
"customs-declaration-number",
"customs-office",
"customs-declaration-date",
"payment-order-reference",
"advance-payment-received-amount",
"series",
"folio-number",
"use-of-invoice",
"form-of-payment",
"type-of-receipt",
"payment-method",
"issuance-place",
"confirmation",
"withholding-tax-override",
"type-of-relationship",
"gross-total",
"registered-company-registration-number",
"registered-company-place-of-registration",
"registered-company-type",
"registered-company-managing-directors",
"credit-reason",
"registered-company-permit-number",
"registered-company-permit-date",
"registered-company-liquidator-name",
"registered-company-share-capital",
"Tax Nature",
"registered-company-unique-shareholder",
"registered-company-liable-company",
"registered-company-tax-regime",
"registered-company-legal-status",
"QST Registration Number",
"Authorised Person",
"Authorised Person Address",
"Authorised Person VAT ID",
"Date of Registration",
"Sole Registration Code",
"origin-currency-net",
"taxes-in-origin-country-currency",
"origin-currency-gross",
"self-billing-reference",
"registered-company-legal-type",
"registered-company-registered-seat",
"registered-company-chairman-of-the-board",
"registered-company-court-of-registration",
"registered-company-liquidation-remark",
"registered-company-commercial-register-number",
"Disputed Invoice Number",
"Channel",
"Taxable Amount",
"invoice-from-code",
"invoice-from-supplier-name",
"invoice-from-street1",
"invoice-from-street2",
"invoice-from-city",
"invoice-from-state",
"invoice-from-postal-code",
"invoice-from-country-code",
"invoice-from-country-name",
"ship-from-code",
"ship-from-supplier-name",
"ship-from-street1",
"ship-from-street2",
"ship-from-city",
"ship-from-state",
"ship-from-postal-code",
"ship-from-country-code",
"ship-from-country-name",
"supplier-tax-registration-number",
"supplier-tax-registration-country-code",
"supplier-tax-registration-country-name",
"supplier-tax-registration-local",
"buyer-tax-registration-number",
"buyer-tax-registration-country-code",
"buyer-tax-registration-country-name",
"buyer-tax-registration-local",
['invoice_lines', 'id']]
```

Comment: The Meta field is optional though. Record path sets the path within the json which you want to make a df. If you don’t supply meta it will only return the values from the record path, and nothing in the parent.

Comment: Hi Ben Pap I want json_normalize to give me as many of the meta fields as possible and skip ones that aren't present.  That's what I mean by making meta fields optional.